# RSA Encryption and Decryption Java

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I am having issues decryption in my code where the values I get from encryption and decryption aren't matching and the value of decryption is always the value of 1. I have attached all my code and would love some help in why this is happening as it has dazzled me a bit.

Comment: generally I would stay away from trying to implement your own encryption, most programming languages will have libraries that you can use. Implementing your own is asking for trouble when it comes to security, interoperability, convenience, ....

Comment: Unfortunately i would love to avoid it, but this is for a uni project where ive been asked not create it from scratch without use of the Java RSA library.

Comment: You never calculate `phi`. Also, you're use of redundant parentheses is sometimes very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
d = (BigInteger.valueOf(1).mod(phi).divide(e));  //check with nick
```

is incorrect, as I'm sure Nick will confirm. You need to compute the [modular inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of e mod phi. In Java this is available as [`BigInteger.modInverse(..)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modInverse-java.math.BigInteger-), so the correct line would be

```
d = e.modInverse(phi);
```

Comment: @Bretty135 and phi is still not initialized (is null) according to the code)

Comment: @Bretty135: Thank you for posting complete code of the problem.